# Variable percentage in ng-circle-progress

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using ng-cycle-progress in my angular progress.
HTML:

```
<circle-progress
  [percent]="score"
  [radius]="100"
  [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
  [innerStrokeWidth]="8"
  [outerStrokeColor]="'#78C000'"
  [innerStrokeColor]="'#C7E596'"
  [animation]="true"
  [animationDuration]="300"
></circle-progress>
```

I'm setting score in my .ts file dynamically. But, I'm getting an error while rendering the progress bar. Can someone help me out here. TIA.

Edit:
The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: "Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CircleProgressComponent -> CircleProgressOptions]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CircleProgressComponent -> CircleProgressOptions]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CircleProgressOptions!
get@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68202:27
resolveToken@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69988:24
tryResolveToken@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69914:16
get@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69777:20
resolveToken@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69988:24
tryResolveToken@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69914:16
get@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69777:20
resolveNgModuleDep@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:93827:29
get@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:94915:16
resolveDep@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:95445:45
createClass@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:95293:29
createDirectiveInstance@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:95109:22
createViewNodes@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:105739:38
callViewAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:106189:13
execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:106094:13
createViewNodes@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:105768:5
createRootView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:105611:5
callWithDebugContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:107140:27
debugCreateRootView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:106377:12
create@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:94251:31
create@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:90215:29
createComponent@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:94407:47
activateWith@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:161557:40
activateRoutes@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:157474:40
activateChildRoutes/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:157411:18
activateChildRoutes@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:157406:29
activate@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:157269:14
activateRoutes/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:157242:10
_next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:225544:35
next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:221057:18
_next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:227911:26
next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:221057:18
_next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:225550:26
next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:221057:18
notifyNext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:227587:26
_next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:220352:21
next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:221057:18
 .......
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Comment: I edited the question. Please check it.

Comment: The error you are getting seems to be unrelated to what you have posted in the OP.

Comment: Please show us your `AppModule`-file. I think you forgot to import the module.

Comment: No, I've imported the module. ->import { NgCircleProgressModule } from 'ng-circle-progress';     ->NgCircleProgressModule, in imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide default `CircleProgressOptions`. Please provide default CircleProgressOptions in the module.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-circle-progress-demo?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

```
NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
      // set defaults here
      radius: 100,
      outerStrokeWidth: 16,
      innerStrokeWidth: 8,
      outerStrokeColor: "#78C000",
      innerStrokeColor: "#C7E596",
      animationDuration: 300,
      ...
})
```

Comment: Hey, this is working perfectly but I have another module which needs initialization using .forRoot. What should I do for that?

Comment: You need to just import `NgCircleProgressModule` for another module.

Comment: or you can create a shared module and import in multiple module.

Answer (score 1):

Change your app.module.ts :

```
import { NgCircleProgressModule } from 'ng-circle-progress';
```

==>

```
import { NgCircleProgressModule } from './ng-circle-progress.module';
```

then import it

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,




  // Specify ng-circle-progress as an import
    NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
      // set defaults here
      radius: 100,
      outerStrokeWidth: 16,
      innerStrokeWidth: 8,
      outerStrokeColor: "#700000",
      innerStrokeColor: "#C7E596",
      animationDuration: 300,
      ...
    })

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Change your app.component.ts :

```
import { CircleProgressComponent, CircleProgressOptions } from 'ng-circle-progress';
```

https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress/issues/42

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-circle-progress